# Regex to capture cells in a CSV file

Tags: regex

I have a CSV file (comma delimited values) and I need a regex formula to capture each cell.

Usually I use the following formula to capture (example a 5 column table)

`(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*)`

The problem with this formula is that if the cell contains a comma, which is possible, then the capture thinks that this comma is another column.
When a csv has a comma inside a column it is enclosed inside two " " to be taken literally.

How can I take into account these commas in my regex?

Comment: Can’t you just use a ‘proper’ CSV parser? (I suppose it’s doable with a regex pattern, but it’s going to be a horrible and hard-to-maintain one.)

Comment: I cant use a csv parser, I have to use regex

Comment: you *cant* use commas as part of a column in a csv file if the separator is a comma! Use a semicolon for a separator instead (;).

Comment: I would need a regex to replace any comma found between " " to a semicolon first. For example "John,Agius" to "John;Agius". Any comma not between " " is left untouched

Comment: What flavour of regex? What program will the regex be used in?

Comment: The program the regex will be used in is Autohotkey

Answer (score -1):

```
RegExReplace(str,",(?![^""]*,*""(,|$))","`n")
```